# MS Access Update on specific SQL select same table

Tags: mysql, ms-access, sql-update

I'm currently trying to update an existing database (removing duplicates).
You can see the structure as follows :

I have a database on which specific entries are marked as "Main". These entries need to be updated with data from duplicate records, only having the same name.

(Updated table to reflect my question better)

It would look like this:

```
+----+------+-----------------+--------------+---------+
| ID | Name | Field-To-Update |  Duplication |  Source |
+----+------+-----------------+--------------+---------+
| .  |  A   |  xxx            |  Main        |       1 |
| .  |  A   |  yyy            |  ""          |       2 |
| .  |  A   |  zzz            |  ""          |       3 |
| .  |  B   |  foo            |  ""          |       1 |
| .  |  B   |  bar            |  Main        |       2 |
+----+------+-----------------+--------------+---------+
```

Should result in

```
+----+------+-----------------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| ID | Name | Field-To-Update |  Duplication |                     Source                    |
+----+------+-----------------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| .  |  A   |  yyy            |  Main        |  1                                            |
| .  |  A   |  yyy            |  ""          |  2                                            |
| .  |  A   |  zzz            |  ""          |  3 (should be updated from a specific source) |
| .  |  B   |  bar            |  ""          |  1                                            |
| .  |  B   |  bar            |  Main        |  2 (should be updated from a specific source) |
+----+------+-----------------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------+
```

Do any of you have an idea how to tackle this?  I've tried with multiple queries for a couple of days now without any success.

Comment: May we see one or more of your attempts, edited in? We frequently get people claiming they have made a solid effort, and in some of those cases, I would say they have made none at all. It is therefore a good idea to differentiate your questions from that kind!

Answer (score 1):

you could use a update with join

```
update  t
set t.field_to_update = x.field_to_update
from your_table t
inner join  ( select name, field_to_update
                          from your_table
                          where Duplication <> 'Main') x
  ) on t.name = x.name
 where t.Duplication = 'Main'
```

Comment: This does not seem to work in access, I tried this type of query before.  It fails on the assignment of "x" on the subquery with as error "missing operator".  Adding AS or something like this does not seem to fix this issue.

Comment: .I'm sorry, .. Wrong sintax .. answer  updated .. too much questions  in my mind ...now should work

Answer (score 0):

Bizarre requirement. You say you are updating to remove duplicates, however, it looks to me like you are creating duplicates.

There are only 2 records for each Name? Try:

```
UPDATE TABLE
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT NAME
        ,[Field-To-Update]
    FROM TABLE
    WHERE Duplication IS NULL
    ) AS Query1 ON TABLE.NAME = Query1.NAME
SET TABLE.[Field-To-Update] = [Query1]![Field-To-Update]
WHERE Duplication = "Main";
```

Name is a reserved word in Access. Should not use reserved words as name for anything.

I tried the `<> "Main"` criteria and it did not work which was surprising - no records returned. So I switched to the `Is Null` parameter.

If you want to pull value from the maximum Source for each Name, then need a query that does that. Review http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html#TopN. Then use that query in the above example as Query1.

Comment: SQL is usually a bit more readable if preformatting (code formatting) is used in preference to a quote block. See @scaisEdge's answer.

Comment: There could be more non-"main" records in the table.  I'm trying to update one record with information I might have from duplicate records.  After this update has been done, all non-"main" records will be deleted.

Comment: If there are multiple "non-main" records for each Name, then what criteria determines which should be used for the update? Do they all have the same value in [Field-to-Update]?

Comment: Is it more clear now? -  sorry, have been looking all day into data sheets

Comment: So what is the criteria? Why is the update from Source 2 for Name A?

Comment: The one with max ID could do the job I think